# How to get span value into a hidden input?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am trying to get a sapn value into an sql table to show that value in other pages.

So here is my code.

I’ve updated my code, the code about many radios and user will choose opthins with number value came from DB then the total will show uo into span value, so I had like to insert the total span value into `$totalprice`. Check here:

```js
var globalSum = 0;
function summerize(formfieldObj) { 
globalSum = 0; 
//loop through div name values 
$(".contact100-form-radio").each(function() { 
//find radio check if checked or not 
if($(this).find("input[type='radio']").is(':checked')){ 
console.log("in"+$(this).find(".values").text()) 
if($(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("name")=="type7"){ 
globalSum = parseInt($(this).find(".values").text()) * globalSum; 

}else{ 
globalSum = parseInt($(this).find(".values").text()) + globalSum; 
}} 
$('#totalprice').html(globalSum); //assign value to div 
}); 
}
```

```css
        #same-line
        {
        display: flex;
        }
        #sameline
        {
        display:inline;
        margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100" data-validate = "Alert, Fill this" >
                    <span class="label-input100">Option 1 *</span>
                    
                    <div class="contact100-form-radio">
                    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio187" type="radio" name="type6" value="10" onclick="summerize(this)">
                    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio17">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <div id="same-line">
                    <div id="sameline" style="direction: rtl;">
                    Option 1
                    </div>
                    <div id="sameline" class="values" style="direction: rtl;">
                    
                    10
                    
                    </div>
                    <div id"sameline">$</div>
                    </div>
                    </font>
                    </font>
                    </label>
                    </div>

                                       <div class="contact100-form-radio">
                    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio18" type="radio" name="type6" value="10" onclick="summerize(this)">
                    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio18">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <div id="same-line">
                    <div id="sameline" style="direction: rtl;">
                    Option 2
                    </div>
                    <div id="sameline" class="values" style="direction: rtl;">
                    
                    20
                    
                    </div>
                    <div id"sameline">$</div>
                    </div>
                    </font>
                    </font>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
<br />
<br />

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100" data-validate = "Alert, Fill this" >
                    <span class="label-input100">Option 2 *</span>
                    
                    <div class="contact100-form-radio">
                    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio19" type="radio" name="type7" value="10" onclick="summerize(this)">
                    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio19">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <div id="same-line">
                    <div id="sameline" style="direction: rtl;">
                    Option 1
                    </div>
                    <div id="sameline" class="values" style="direction: rtl;">
                    
                    30
                    
                    </div>
                    <div id"sameline">$</div>
                    </div>
                    </font>
                    </font>
                    </label>
                    </div>

                                       <div class="contact100-form-radio">
                    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio20" type="radio" name="type7" value="10" onclick="summerize(this)">
                    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio20">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <div id="same-line">
                    <div id="sameline" style="direction: rtl;">
                    Option 2
                    </div>
                    <div id="sameline" class="values" style="direction: rtl;">
                    
                    40
                    
                    </div>
                    <div id"sameline">$</div>
                    </div>
                    </font>
                    </font>
                    </label>
                    </div>


<div class="wrap-input100 bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
                    <span class="label-input100" style="color:red">Total Price *</span>
                    <br />
                    Total : <span id="totalprice">0</span> $
                    <input type="hidden" name="totalprice" id="totalprice" value="77">
                    <br />
Note: text
                </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dcsh4o3/

Comment: shouldnt you be using .val() instead of .html() method?

Comment: do you really need to give them same id, it will create confusion for JS.

Comment: Please add more html code you using in js

Comment: What is **contact100-form-radio** in js , please add complete code , For more help.

Comment: The hidden input field and the span tag have same ids given to them. Change their ids as well.

Comment: It doesn’t work too

Comment: simply you can write `$('input[name="totalprice"]').val(globalSum);` after line `$('#totalprice').html(globalSum);` check if that work .

Comment: Hey Swati, thank you for your comment, I added it but still not working

Comment: @HatemAlshehri What didn't work here ? can you elaborate ? value is not showing under that input box ? Its working see here -> https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/f4deLkch/

Comment: @Swati I want that value insert into $totalprice rather than 77. So when I added $('#totalprice').html(globalSum); that span value shows on the input but after send it, it doesn’t fo to the DB

Comment: So you mean values are showing in input fields but are not getting send to db ?Is this under form tag ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220262/discussion-between-swati-and-hatem-alshehri).